# Load test Application + WCF service

Tags: wcf, testing, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I want to **load test** an application having its own **WCF** service using **Visual Studio 2012**. I tried creating a **web performance test** and use it with load test but, web performance is not recording the intermediate request send to service which is very much required.

Using **CodedUI** with it not feasible since it does not put on that much load and and its interactive.

The application is on different server and service too.

Any suggestion to accomplish this in VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

Use dedicated "Unit Tests" for this. VS Load Tests can execute Coded UI/Web Performance or Unit Test.

In your Unit Tests, simply use a standard WCF proxy, channelfactory or RestClient.

Just check that you dispose well a Web Service Proxy class